# With hypervisor, How to surveillance the time when target process is created or terminated

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, intel, hypervisor

I would like to make my hypervisor on linux for detecting and surveillance target process like a malware.
To achieve this, the hypervisor need to detect processes that is created or terminated or task switched.

On intel CPU, I knew that cr3 register indicate those roles.
for example, when cr3 register value is changed, `vmexit` caused. And it means executed process will be changed (task switch or create process).

To achieve my goal, I thought this mechanism is very userful.

However, to detect created process and terminated process, it needs to scan task_struct when `vmexit` due to changed cr3 value.
Especially, compare task_struct with target process lists to detect and remove terminated process from target process lists.

Could you tell me the best practice or teach me OSS like mine.

On Windows, I would be able to use `PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutine` API....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly what [linux perf](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) does on linux, you could enable the two trace points which will be called upon process start and exit:

```
# perf list
  sched:sched_process_exec                           [Tracepoint event]
  sched:sched_process_exit                           [Tracepoint event]
  sched:sched_process_fork                           [Tracepoint event]
  ....
```

You can play with tracepoint by enable it with debugfs:

```
cd /sys/kernel/debug/tracing
echo sched:sched_process_fork >> set_event
echo sched:sched_process_exit >> set_event
echo 1 > tracing_on
cat trace_pipe
```

You will get output like this:

```
       <...>-115924 [001] .... 1853164.915266: sched_process_fork: comm=bash pid=115924 child_comm=bash child_pid=115970
       <...>-115970 [002] .... 1853164.915864: sched_process_exit: comm=bash pid=115970 prio=120
       <...>-115924 [001] .... 1853164.916147: sched_process_fork: comm=bash pid=115924 child_comm=bash child_pid=115971
       <...>-115971 [003] .... 1853164.916655: sched_process_exit: comm=bash pid=115971 prio=120
       <...>-115924 [001] .... 1853165.502237: sched_process_fork: comm=bash pid=115924 child_comm=bash child_pid=115972
       <...>-115972 [003] .... 1853165.503027: sched_process_exit: comm=cat pid=115972 prio=120
       <...>-115924 [001] .... 1853176.627842: sched_process_fork: comm=bash pid=115924 child_comm=bash child_pid=115973
       <...>-115973 [003] .... 1853176.628515: sched_process_exit: comm=cat pid=115973 prio=120
       <...>-115924 [001] .... 1853184.520488: sched_process_fork: comm=bash pid=115924 child_comm=bash child_pid=115974
```

As you can see, each time a process is forked or terminated, the event is displayed. Also the `trace_pipe` is a pipe, so that you can wait on and read it in your program.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to determine whether a process was created or destroyed from the Hypervisor. You can cause `VMEXIT` to occur when either one of these instructions have been executed:

```
mov cr3, ...
mov ..., cr3
```

This is not enough. The only information you can gather from this is "This CR3 value belongs to a process that exists/used to exist".